# Project in AndroidStudio will not build after update

Tags: android-studio

After updating AndroidStudio, one of my projects does not build. I have not managed to find a working solution. I have tried deleting different folders and cached files. I also tried re-installing android studio, but nothing have helped.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2430: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: /home/erikbylow/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/a3d9a3af204f4221527c5ec7986f58cd/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
Output:  /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-55: AAPT: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: /home/erikbylow/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux.jar/a3d9a3af204f4221527c5ec7986f58cd/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux/aapt2 compile --legacy \
        -o \
        /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
        /home/erikbylow/Code/privateprojects/workspace-android/TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #2
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error you are getting:

> TailoredDictFire/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2430: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

AAPT2 is telling you that there is a resource on line 2430 in the merged values file that has an incorrect value - it should be either a resource reference or empty. If I remember correctly, this is when you define an ID resource and put for example a string or an integer as a value for it. It should either not have a value at all, or should be a reference to a different ID ("@id/other_id").

Look at what resource is in that line. Do you recognize it as coming from your app? If you did define it, make sure you fix it in your values files (`app/src/main/res/values`):

```
<id name="my_id">my value</id> -> <id name="my_id" />
```

If it comes from an external library, you can try overriding it by defining a resource with a matching type and name in your resources.

Comment: Actually looking through the stacktrace again I do see it is coming from your values file: TailoredDictFire/app/src/main/res/values/ids.xml:3:5-55. Fix the ID value there and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I do not really know where the item come from, maybe a mistake at some point. I just removed it and it worked.